# Create a Raspberry Pi webserver with a domain name

Tags: web-server, apache-httpd

I just set up my Apache web-server ([following a tutorial from Jeremy Morgan](http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi/how-to-raspberry-pi-web-server/)), and since I have a domain name (pillower.com) registered with GoDaddy, I was wondering how I could link them. Would changing the forwarding settings on GoDaddy be my best bet?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to [forward port 80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to your Raspberry Pi. Then you have to tell GoDaddy that you want them to have the IP of your domain name updated as soon as you get a new IP (Dynamic DNS). Maybe you should [use GoDaddy with DynDNS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1825140).

Comment: GoDaddy does not support DynDNS. You need to do it using cnames.

Answer (score 3):

If your pi is behind a router, make sure NAT / port forwarding / Virtual Server is forwarding port 80 to your pi's IP.

And then, tell goDaddy to point A record to your external IP using DNS manager.
You could also create a CNAME that forwards www.domain.com to your IP or your dynamic host ( whatever.no-ip.com )